# Simple Dropdown list from List<model>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The model

```
@model List<Survey.SurveyQuestion>
```

SurveyQuestion has two properties, `QuestionId` and `QuestionText`

```
Html.DropDownList("Questions", new SelectList(@Model))

@Html.DropDownList("Questions", new SelectList(@Model), "QuestionId", "QuestionText")
```

**Output from above code:**

[image: Output from above code:]

Unable to use DropDownListFor as it does not recognize field **QuestionId** (or infact any field).

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(item => item.QuestionId, new SelectList(Model, 
    "QuestionId", "QuestionText"), "--Select --"))
```

The below code displays all data correctly:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>@item.QuestionId - @item.QuestionText</p>
}
```

Comment: whats strange about this is your are NOT using a dropdownlistfor. I would recommend it, but since you're not, the error is odd.

Comment: problem is @Html.DropDownListFor(item => item.QuestionId ...), the QuestionId is not recognized, compiler error.

Comment: which we could tackle, IF YOU WERE USING A DROPDOWNLISTFOR. I'm stumped cause i see you using a dropdownlist -- no FOR

Comment: Updated with DropDownListFor code. It does not compile.

Comment: OK, dropdownlist for requires a model variable to bind to with a lambda. do you know what that means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting up your `SelectList` wrong. Try this instead (**added linespaces for readability on SO**):

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "Questions",
     Model.Select(m => new SelectListItem 
         {
             Value = m.QuestionId.ToString(),
             Text = m.QuestionText
         }))
```

Comment: yup, thats it. I shouldve looked closer.

Comment: @DaveA Hehe yeah those html helper overloads can be a nightmare, mixing the order ofhtml attributes and route values on an actionlink always catches me out :)

Comment: Thanks, geez, so stupid of me... just mixed the order. This @Html.DropDownList("QuestionId", new SelectList(@Model, "QuestionId", "QuestionText")) also works.

Comment: @AseemGautam Np glad I could help :). Just a side note, you don't need the `@` before the word `Model`, as you're already in Razor code (inside the `DropDownList` call) :)